# How can I disable the JVM on a Windows platform for running background matlab scripts

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file, background, jvm

I found a similar question here that doesn't help me so I'm asking my own.
I have a matlab script that perfectly works under linux with nohup command.
Unfortunately, I need to run that on windows also. But I can't understand why my command still doesn't work.
My script does a certain loop but after the first it stops giving me an error about the java or something. I must tell you that the same problem occur under linux if I don't put the `-nodisplay` command.

My batch line is the following

`matlab -nodisplay -automation -r "run('myfile.m')" -logfile output.txt -minimize`

Please help me.

edit:
I think I found my issue the problem is when I use `-nodisplay` under linux the command `usejava('awt')` works because my java environment is disabled, however this does not happen under windows! Why?

**second edit:**
I think I found something that is quite similar to what I needed.

```
matlab -noawt -noFigureWindows -r "run('myfile.m')" -logfile output.txt -minimize
```

The analysis runs, without saying nothing, but the MATLAB command window still opens minimized..uhm
I'd rather having anything to open up!

I must add another thing..`nohup` never waits and go forward until it reaches the end of the script, nevertheless using any other batch command such as `start` if there is any input request or "wait" it stops until someone gives an input!

Comment: Is this the related question: [Running matlab in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000724/)?

Comment: @EitanT nope that question is about UNIX/Linux systems

Comment: But there's no `nohup` in Windows, a windows process should still live after its parent is killed... What is it that you want to do exactly then?

Comment: Think we need to know more about your environment. Can you include the exact "error about the java or something" output in your question? Are you running this from the Windows command line in a local desktop session? RDP? Do you stay logged in until the Matlab run completes? (`nohup` isn't needed to outlast parent process on Windows, but it'll probably still get killed if the user logs out of the desktop session that launched it, which is sort of analagous to a terminal disconnection on Unix.)

Comment: @AndrewJanke the exact error is related to some java object that I have in my code (which runs in UI mode and not) I don't know why even with the `-nodisplay` option matlab continues to go into `usejava('awt')` it shouldn't use any java. The same things happens with `-nojvm` and `-nodesktop`

Comment: The exact error message text, copied and pasted in to the question, would really help.

Comment: I believe the question you mean to be asking is **"How can I disable the JVM on a Windows platform?"**  As far as I can tell, there is no known solution published online.  Matlab's documentation is very specific in stating that `-nodesktop` and `-nojvm` are commands specific to Unix-y platforms.  I'd wager you'll get a better response if you reword your question to specifically ask this.

Comment: Though it is not stated for windows, first I would try whether the `-nojvm` option works. If not, try looking into this: [Full list of startup options for windows](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html)

Comment: @MattB.that's exactely what I meant!

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin already know that link, thanks

Comment: Put NirCmd (`nircmd.exe exec hide ...`) together with `-noawt` and `-noFigureWindows` and you have what you need.  See my answer.  :)

Comment: @chappjc I'll try it as soon as I can today!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The undocumented `-noawt` option will prevent the GUI functionality, but let Java run.  Combine that with `-noFigureWindows`, as you discovered, and you should have what you need.  Alternatively, you can [turn off figure display via your M file](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-7RK35B/) with `set(0,'DefaultFigureVisible','off')`.

To see if Java actually loaded, run `ver` or `version -java`.  Here's what I see with `-nojvm`.

[image: Windows MATLAB with no Java]

Then, using Windows' `start /b /min MATLAB.exe ...`  should launch it minimized and without holding a command window opened.

To make MATLAB **invisible** try using the tiny [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) command line tool as follows,

```
nircmd.exe exec hide win64\MATLAB.exe -noawt -noFigureWindows -nosplash -minimize ...
```

I think that should do it, **but** make sure you start the actual `MATLAB.exe` in the `bin\<architecture>` folder, not just `bin\matlab.exe` because when it launches the actual MATLAB.exe, it will not be hidden.

Comment: So are you telling me that there is no command for windows to prevent java for running..that's sound strange to me. Thanks for the answer for now.

Comment: Well, as Dennis said, `-nojvm` **should** work for Windows too.  When MATLAB starts, the `ver`command will tell you if it started Java.

Comment: I'll give -nojvm a try even though I already tried that. But I'm pretty sure that was -noawt that I missed..we'll see

Comment: You mean linux only?  Yes, according to the docs, but it works on my 32-bit laptop MATLAB install.

Comment: Thanks @chappjc for the tip but to prevent windows to show up you must use the `-noFigureWindows`. But I can't solve the problem of opening the command window